# How-to create Html.EditorFor for numeric input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

Simple, I want to build an editor that only accept numbers, as I do, you can use javascript on change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use javascript, but it gets dicey.  You have to trap every keystroke so stay away from things like Jquery which only slow it down.  Also keypad is different from number keys so you have to be aware of those.  Also you have to pass through things like tab, backspace, space ( sometimes but not always ), del key, insert etc. not to mention the period on the keyboard and on the keypad if you are doing fixed point decimals.

This is one of the **major** weaknesses of the DOM model and HTML so you ahve to code around it.  Google for "javascript+keycode" and you will find lots of examples.